# Defining Additional Methods in a Scrapy Class

Tags: python, scrapy

How is a Scrapy class executed and how do you include additional methods to a spider class?

For example, from the docs:

```
import scrapy

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

If I wanted to define some methods for polling a database or something else, how might I go about that, and why?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what do you want to poll the database for? Thanks.

Comment: URLs to crawl, for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look on the following use case - getting the urls to crawl from a database. For this, instead of `start_urls`, you need to use [`start_requests()` method](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests).

Sample code (using `MySQLdb` driver directly):

```
import MySQLdb
import scrapy

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]

    def start_requests(self):
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host="host", user="user" ...) 
        cursor = db.cursor()

        cursor.execute("SELECT url from url_table")
        requests = [scrapy.Request(url=row[0]) for row in cursor.fetchall()]

        cursor.close()

        return requests

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: How I currently have it set up is outside of the class completely, are the class methods just executed from top down or is it only predefined methods which are allowed, i.e. the start_requests method?

Comment: @Adders this particular use case involves using the `start_requests()` method which is a special one - specially designed for providing the start urls dynamically. But, aside from special "built-in" methods it's just a regular Python class.